# Override virtual function through CRTP base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions, crtp

**Old:** How can I override a virtual function through a CRTP base class?

```
struct I { virtual void foo() = 0; };

template<class D>
struct B { void foo() { } }; // provides implementation of foo in D

struct D : I, B<D> { }; // D has an implementation of foo that should override I

int main() { D d; }
```

`Error: unimplemented pure virtual method 'foo' in 'D'`

**Simpler:** How can I override a virtual function without reimplementing it in a derived type? (I guess this question goes against the definition of a virtual function).

```
struct I { virtual void foo() = 0; };

struct B { void foo() { } };

struct D : B, I { };

int main() { D d; }
```

Comment: No. A `B` is not an `I`. `B` could implement a part of `I`'s interface but not all of it.

Comment: something must inherit from I and implement foo. one possibility would be to have D do that and forward to B. Or you could add another template parameter to B and have B inherit from there. There are countless possibilities, just one is needed: something must inherit from I and implement it there.

Comment: `D` inherits from `I` and has a `foo` implementation (provided by `B`). Having a `foo` implementation is not enough? I could reimplement it in `D` with a dummy function that calls `B<D>::foo` from it but I don't like that solution.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the obvious  but clunky `void foo() { B::foo(); }` solution, you could separate the "implements a `foo`" interface from the more complete interface `I`:

```
struct FooInterface {
    virtual ~FooInterface() {}
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct I : public virtual FooInterface {};

template<class D>
struct B : public virtual FooInterface { void foo() { } };

struct D : I, B<D> {};

int main() { D d; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you're needlessly mixing two different concepts: crtp, and inheriting an implementation of a virtual function

crtp is used for compile time polyrmorphism, virtual functions for runtime polymorphism

that said, you can inherit in an implementation of a virtual function by way of **dominance** in a virtual inheritance hierarchy, which yields roughly the effect of java/c# implementation inheritance

---

example:

```
struct tutti_i
{
    virtual int frutti() const = 0;
};

struct tutti_impl_1
    : virtual tutti_i
{
    int frutti() const override { return 42; }
};

struct base
    : virtual tutti_i
{};

struct derived
    : base
    , tutti_impl_1
{};

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    tutti_i&& tutti = derived();
    std::cout << tutti.frutti() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I removed the CRTP in the simpler part of the question. I guess it shows better what I was trying to do which does not make much sense.

Comment: Hm, it seemed at first that the answer didn't answer the original question, since the asker seemed to want to use CRTP. I should have read the comments on the question before downvoting. It's locked now though, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `D::foo()` as a trivial wrapper calling `B<D>::foo()`.  If you have a lot of places that would need to do this, you could make a macro to help out, like:

```
#define WRAP(CLASS, METHOD) \
    METHOD() { return CLASS::METHOD(); }

struct D : I, B<D>
{
    void WRAP(B<D>, foo);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't care whether or not B inherits from I, you can also implement this with CRTP as originally asked:

```
struct I { virtual void foo() = 0; };

template <class D>
struct B : I { void foo(){ /* Do something fancy with D's type */ } };

struct D : B<D> { };
```

And if you need further inheritance so that the implementation of foo is always of the most-derived type, you can introduce an intermediate type to disambiguate which implementation of foo gets used:

```
struct I { virtual void foo() = 0; };

template <class T>
struct B : virtual I { void foo() { /* Do something fancy with the most-derived type */ }};

struct D : B<D> { };

template <typename Base, typename Derived>
struct InheritFrom : public Base, public B<D> { void foo() { B<D>::foo(); } };

struct FurtherDerived : InheritFrom<D, FurtherDerived> { };
```